# How to fetch the result data from HTML form?

Tags: php, html

sorry to ask this dummy question. I have an HTML form like below that will result in a bunch of data lines to be parsed later by my PHP codes. But I get a bit stuck for how to get the data before I can parse and process it.

```
    <form method="post" action="https://domain.com/cgi-bin/cgi.exe">
    <input name="exec" value="viewproduct" type="hidden">
    <input name="customer" value="customer_name" type="hidden">
    <input name="sku" value="sku_number" type="hidden"> <br>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

I need to store the result data in a string variable that I can parse it later line by line into multiple arrays.

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting to parse the result data - you'll likely need to use AJAX for that . . . actual handling of this will vary greatly depending on the format of the data you're getting back, as well as what you want to do with it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to use ajax instead.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Can you give an example of how to use ajax for this form and save the response data to a string variable?

Answer (score 0):

1. Submit the data to (via the action attribute) a PHP program instead of a compiled Windows executable
2. Use `$_POST['form_control_name']`

Answer (score 0):

$_POST holds your formdata. Access data like:

```
  $_POST['exec'];
```

To string with for example delimiter ','

```
  implode(',', $_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_POST[]` array.

```
$exec = $_POST['exec'];
$customer = $_POST['customer'];
$sku = $_POST['sku'];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not retrieving those 3 form values, instead a bunch of response values (product title, price, etc) from the server after entering those 3 parameters.